# Improve thermal effeciency of buck LED driver with fixed supply rail

Tags: buck, heat, led-driver, step-down

I have this driver circuit that uses an [ILD8150](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ILD8150_ILD8150E-DataSheet-v01_04-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462696dbf120169ba96613f4c20):

[image]

There are two identical sections of this module on my PCB.
One powers 6 LEDs the other powers only 2 LED. The Vf of the LEDs is 2.85V @ 350 mA.
So the first LED string has a nominal voltage of 17.1V the other only of 5.7V.

This leads to a greater heat dissipation on the second driver with a gap of 24-5.7 = 18.3V.

Since I cannot change the power rail that is fixed at 24 V, is there any improvement to the circuit so I can reduce the power dissipation of the second module?

Comment: Do you really have no output capacitor?  What is the peak current through that "600mA" inductor?

Comment: How did you measure the greater dissipation? What is the temperature difference? What component is overheating?

Comment: @user1850479 yes, I don't have. How should calculate it? The ds does not show any design hint. I can try to measure the peak current. I just selected it roughly doubling the nominal current.

Comment: @bobflux I just felt the increase of temperature and a cheap thermocamera seems to detect a hotspot on D4. The difference in temperature about the other circuits is about +30 °C

Comment: @user1850479 about the Cout. I found some notes I wrote several month ago. An app notes state: "due to the relatively low output ripple current, a capacitor in parallel to the LEDs is not needed in many applications.". As far as I understand the cap only reduce the ripple, am I right?

Answer (score 3):

> I just felt the increase of temperature and a cheap thermocamera seems to detect a hotspot on D4. The difference in temperature about the other circuits is about +30 °C

The output voltage of a buck converter is Vin*D with input voltage Vin and duty cycle D (between 0 and 1).

The MOSFET conducts during a time interval D*Period, and the diode conducts during the rest of the period, so (1-D)*Period.

On the converter with lower output voltage, duty cycle D will be lower, so the diode will conduct during a longer time and dissipate more power.

So if both converters have the same output current, it is normal that the diode heats more on the converter with lower output voltage.

If this is a problem, you can use a diode with better thermal resistance (usually a bigger package) and several vias from anode to ground plane to sink away the heat. This will not make the efficiency better. It is not recommended to add copper area to the switching node (diode cathode) because any capacitance to ground on this node must be charged and discharged on each cycle, so more capacitance causes more losses.

The solution for higher efficiency at low duty cycle is to use a synchronous converter, which replaces the diode with a MOSFET, having lower voltage drop.

Answer (score 2):

You could choose a different regulator IC, but with the one you're using there aren't many "knobs" to turn to improve efficiency.

Efficiency will naturally be lower with higher conversion ratios, so your results are not unexpected.  The one path to substantially improve efficiency is choosing a different inductor with lower DCR and possibly also lower core loss.

Since the part is hysteretic current controlled, A larger inductance will lower the switching frequency (and keep the same ripple current) resulting in lower core and switching loss at the expense of worse transient response and larger physical size, especially if you reduce the DCR at the same time.

So experiment with a larger inductor value, or choose a different controller.

Comment: This answer was given before the OP added the comment about the diode being the hot spot.  Bobflux's answer below is correct for that case (+1).  A synchronous buck part would improve efficiency in that case.